# Settings cannot be modified LightDM GTK+ for Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, lightdm, gtk, settings

I installed Lubuntu 18.04 on an old 32 bits computer. I do not like the default UI and its weird icons (including those for Firefox and other famous ones) eg for gnome's but the LightDM GTK+ settings does not apply any of my changes. Here is for example what I tried to set, with gnome icons and whatever the choice I can make in the list, the UI remains absolutely the same. Is there something to fix first or another way to bypass this issue?

[LightDM GTK+ settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh8gP.png)

Comment: "*do not like the default UI*" makes me think of the desktop itself, but then you talk mostly about changing the greeter (`lightdm`).  It may help if you clarify it's only the greeter you're asking about (as per your provided picture) and not the appearance settings (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Theming)

Comment: I would say, as I could not make any change in the greeter, I cannot sure if changing it would be enough. Above all I would like to change the icons

Comment: I recall changing it years ago, but Lubuntu switched to using `sddm` (*cosmic*,  I didn't like `sddm` at first, feeling a *feature* (*design choice*) was a bug initially), I got used to it, before deciding I preferred that *design choice* and switched my *bionic* boxes to using `sddm` as well.  I recall having issues with `lightdm` too, but eventually got what I wanted (or close enough) but i was too long ago. If I have time I'll have a look, but maybe days & hopefully you'll get help from others in the mean time.  You could always *swap out* `lightdm` (pros & cons of course)